# Any ideas why Ettercap filters aren't seeing packet data?

Tags: security, testing

I'm using an Ettercap filter to detect a query response coming back from a particular service on a remote machine. When I see a response from the service, I'm searching through the data in the packet to see if an offset is a specific value, and if so I'm changing the value at another offset.

Trouble is, when I try this on a new virtual machine I built my Ettercap filter's no longer getting any data in the DATA.data variable available to it.

```
if(ip.proto == TCP && tcp.src == 17867) {
  msg("Response seen!\n");

  if(DATA.data + 2 == "\0x01") {
    msg("Flag detected!\n");

    DATA.data + 5 = 0x09;
  }
}
```

The filter's getting applied to the traffic because "Response seen!" messages get printed out by Ettercap. However, "Flag detected!" messages do not. I **think** DATA.data is indeed empty because if I change my second "if" statement to check for `DATA.data == ""` then the "Flag detected!" message gets printed.

Any ideas why this may be happening?!

Also, if this is the wrong site to be asking questions like this, please let me know. I wasn't sure if it fit better here or somewhere like superuser or serverfault.

Comment: Hmmm... should have probably asked this over at IT Security - Stack Exchange. Is it okay for me to cross-post over there?

Comment: FYI... I just cross-posted this over at [IT Security - StackExchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2285/any-ideas-why-ettercap-filters-arent-seeing-packet-data).

Comment: Maybe you should be using Wireshark.   Also this might be better for serverfault.

Comment: Yeah, I did try wireshark, and indeed verified that the packets do have data in them that Ettercap filters should be seeing. Not sure what the problem is. :(

Answer (score 0):

It could be an encoding problem. For debugging purposes try printing out the value of DATA.data + 2 to see what it actually is and that the length matches.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. (ettercap receives `null (0x00)` characters or `0x20` (DECODED ONE)). I tried to compile `ettercap` from source and everything works fine.
try to log what ever `ettercap` receives using `LOG` filter and then see what is received. if it's bunch off `nulls` or `zeros`, your problem is probably like mine!
it seems to be some problem in etterfilter or ettercap itself.

change your `ettercap` version and it will work (mine did).
my problem was in backtrack 5 `r1` and it's `ettercap`. I updated `ettercap` and everything works fine.

Comment: Thanks @MAGMAG for the suggestion. I'm at a point where I need to be able to do this again so I'll try your suggestion and see if it works.